# Define option outside wp-config.php (on WordPress.com)

Tags: wp-config, pods-framework

Using the PODS plugin.  I need to [add nested shortcode support](https://pods.io/docs/build/using-shortcodes-pods-templates/) which normally would be in the `wp-config.php`, but wordpress.com does not allow editing the core WordPress files.

The change is:

```
define('PODS_SHORTCODE_ALLOW_SUB_SHORTCODES', true);
```

Is there an alternate way of defining this and achieving similar functionality?

Comment: Don't understand. The wp-config.php file can be modified by the end user. Any WP updates will not affect that file. There is an area that you can use for your own DEFINEs in there.

Comment: "wordpress.com does not allow editing the core WordPress files"

Comment: Oops. Missed that part. Thanks. The answer below might work, though. Although I am not a wordpress.com user - I host my own sites.

Comment: afaik, "wordpress.com also does not allow using plugins" – is your site selfhosted using WordPress.org or hosted by WordPress.com?

Answer (score 1):

OK, for those who need, you can do the following:

- Install Code Snippets
- In a code snippet:

  add_filter( 'init', function( )  {
      define('PODS_SHORTCODE_ALLOW_SUB_SHORTCODES', true);
  });

That will define it without modifying `wp-config.php`